# Difference between std::shared_ptr<Type> and Type^

Tags: c++, c++11, windows-runtime, c++-cx

I don't really understand the difference between a shared_ptr and the new handle notation (^) in C++/CX. From what I've read they seem to do the same thing regarding reference counting and memory management. What am I missing?

```
std::shared_ptr<Type>
//vs
Type^
```

Comment: Removed [C++] and [C++11] tags, as the syntax `Type^` is not proper in any of the two versions of the language leading to the obvious answer: *The difference is that one is a c++11 construct and the other is not*

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas:  It looks like the tags were not removed?  In any case, I'd be inclined to leave the tags as-is.  Whereas `T^` is a C++/CX feature, `std::shared_ptr<T>` is a C++ feature, and the question is asking about both.

Comment: @JamesMcNellis: It does look like the tags were not removed, does it not? :) If you believe they should be there I am fine by it. My understanding (which might be due to plain ignorance) is that `std::shared_ptr` is available in c++/CX (i.e. the question is not about comparing features in different languages, but rather about comparing two features available in one particular language.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Solely considering lifetime management, these are the same:  a `shared_ptr<T>` holds a strong (owning) reference to a `T` object; a `T^` does the same.  `make_shared<T>` is roughly equivalent to `ref new T` in C++/CX.

If everywhere you see a `T^` you think `shared_ptr<T>` or `ComPtr<T>` or `CComPtr<T>`, then that's okay--the lifetime management is roughly the same.

How lifetime management works under the hood is different, though:  every `T` type for which `T^` is well-formed is a Windows Runtime reference type that implements the `IUnknown` interface, so the `T` object is internally reference counted<sup>(*)</sup>.  `shared_ptr<T>` supports arbitrary types and uses external reference counting (i.e., it allocates its own reference counting mechanism to control the lifetime of the object).

For weak references, `shared_ptr<T>` has `weak_ptr<T>`, and `T^` has `WeakReference`.  `WeakReference` is not strongly-typed, but you can easily write a strongly-typed reference wrapper around it.  Otherwise, weak references work as you would expect them to.  Support for weak references is optional:  not all reference types support weak references, but most do.

<sup>(*) There is one exception:  `Platform::String^`, which is not a Windows Runtime reference type, but is handled specially for a variety of reasons.  You can think of it as being the same as any other `T^` with respect to lifetime management, though.</sup>

---

So, why do Windows Runtime types wear hats in C++/CX?  Why isn't a library solution like `shared_ptr<T>` or `ComPtr<T>` used?

It's because you never really have a pointer (or a hat) to a concrete runtime type:  you can only interact with an object via a pointer to one of the interfaces that its type implements.  Windows Runtime also does not support interface or class inheritance:  every interface must derive directly from `IInspectable`, and class inheritance is emulated through the use of COM aggregation.

In short, there's no library solution that would result in natural looking C++ code with static type safety.  Function calls, derived-to-base conversions, and interface conversions usually require a call to `QueryInterface` to get the right interface pointer.

You can do this with a library solution (see, for example, the WRL library, or pretty much any COM code), but you can't support C++ language features like implicit conversions or `dynamic_cast`.  Without the hats, you're stuck dealing solely with interface pointers and having to call `QueryInterface` yourself.

---

(If you're interested in the rationale behind *why* the C++/CX language extension were developed and how the C++/CLI syntax ended up being selected for reuse, I'd recommend Jim Springfield's post on this blog from last year, ["Inside the C++/CX Design"](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2011/10/20/10228473.aspx).  Also of note is [episode 3 of GoingNative](http://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/C9-GoingNative/GoingNative-3-The-CCX-Episode-with-Marian-Luparu), in which Marian Luparu discusses C++/CX.)

Comment: What a great answer... Thanks a lot James.

Comment: @James McNellis Thanks. Springfield's post was useful while studying how my C++ background should fit in developing apps targeting RT. Still such spontaneous answer is great aid to mastering grip on the new platform.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell, the latter lacks support for <strike>weak references and</strike> custom deallocation functions.

Note that the former, being more general, accepts any type (in principle), and for safety and cleanliness calls for the use of the helper function `make_shared`. The latter is supported at a language level. That means code like this is safe in C++/CX:

```
some_function(ref new foo(), ref new bar());
```

While in C++, you need to do this:

```
// bad: if foo is allocated but bar's allocation throws, you leak!
some_function(new foo(), new bar());

// good: both never make it anywhere but into a shared_ptr, no leaks
some_function(make_shared<foo>(), make_shared<bar>());
```

Other than that, sure, they implement the same concept. If you're in C++/CX land, use the latter syntax for simplicity and uniformity; if you're trying to stick to standard C++, or are wrapping an existing resource management scheme into a reference-counted scheme, then you'll want the former.

Comment: C++/CX has `WeakReference`.  More [on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh699859.aspx).